# Iterating through rows in .txt and looping each "15 rows"

Tags: python, list, stream, rows

I have a problem with my python script. I can't find a way to do a calculation for the first 15 rows only, then for the second 15 rows only, then for the third 15 rows only... The rows come from a txt file.

```
with open('/Users/sammtt/data/test2.txt','r') as f:
for line in nonblank_lines(f):
    print(my_txt(line,0))
    print(my_txt(line,2))

    print(my_txt(line,6))
    print(my_txt(line,8))
```

Many thanks

Comment: Just append all the lines to a list and then do your calculations.

Comment: Yes but how to skip every 15 rows, to have: the first list with the first 15 rows, the second list with 15 rows etc...

Comment: What about using `enumerate`? if rowNum % 15  == 0 then next 15 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) for [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) from the standard library:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Applying it to your code:

```
with open('/Users/sammtt/data/test2.txt','r') as f:
    for chunk in grouper(nonblank_lines(f), 15):
        process_chunk(chunk)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have an error saying NameError: name 'zip_longest' is not defined

Comment: @sammtt: `zip_longest` needs to be imported from `itertools` (see the update).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` on an integer division:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> f = range(0, 100)
>>> for i, g in groupby(f, key=lambda x: x//15):
...     print(list(g))
...
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
[30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44]
[45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]
[60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74]
[75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89]
[90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
```

And in the case of your file object, you could use `enumerate` to step through the lines:

```
with open('/Users/sammtt/data/test2.txt','r') as f:
    for i, group_of_15 in groupby(enumerate(nonblank_lines(f)), key=lambda x: x[0]//15):
        chunk = list(map(lambda x: x[1], group_of_15))
        do_something(chunk)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. However, I don't really understand how it works then. Is a chunk a box of 15 rows? How do I get the first row of the chunk? By setting nonblank_lines[0] for example?

Comment: Yes, 15 rows/lines. `chunk[0]` should get you the first row.

Comment: I did     for i, group_of_15 in groupby(enumerate(nonblank_lines(f)), key=lambda x: x[0]//15):
        chunk = map(lambda x: x[1], group_of_15)
        print(chunk[0])

But I get TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @sammtt Ah, you should have added a python 3 tag to the question. I thought this was Python 2. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I'm doing chunk[0] to get for example the first 15 rows, but it actually gets the first row of each 15 rows. How can I get just the first block (ie. the first 15 rows for example )?

Comment: @sammtt I don't get the *it actually gets the first row of each 15 rows*. Do you need only those 15 rows and not the others?

Comment: I need a list of the first 15 rows first, then a second list of the next 15 rows, then a third list of the next 15 rows etc... I'd like to get the first list for example by doing chunk[0]. However, I'd like to be able to iterate through the 15 rows of this first list too.

Comment: Each `chunk` at each iteration is a list of 15 rows. So for an iteration, you can only access the rows in the list of 15. If you need to keep the results of previous iterations, you can create a new list that appends each chunk from each iteration. Let me know if this is clear enough. you can also do `for row in chunk: ...` to iterate through each list of 15 rows